# What are forge cores in Clicker Heroes?

Tags: clicker-heroes

Today's update introduced Relics, which are items, of which one can drop per ascension after level 99.

I noticed on the overview page, that there is now also something called "Forge Cores". What are they, how do I get them and what do I do with them?

[image: SCreenshot of the items]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, they do nothing. In the future they will be used to upgrade relics. You get them by salvaging relics.

http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Relics

> What do Forge Cores do?
>
> As of v0.19, Forge Cores does absolutely nothing. Fragsworth
>   (ClickerHeroes dev) has vaguely mentioned that "forge cores will be
>   used to upgrade items". By items, it's safe to assume he means relics.
>   As far as the scope of what Forge Cores will be capable of, only time
>   will tell when it's implemented. Right now it's just all speculations.
>   How do I get Forge Cores?
>
> You can obtain Forge Cores when you salvage a relic. The amount of
>   Forge Cores a relic is worth depends on the rarity as well as the
>   level of it. However, the value of a relic seems to leans towards the
>   level of it more, rather than the actual rarity. As an example, a
>   level 50 common relic will give more forge cores than a level 40 rare
>   relic.

Answer (score 11):

[According to the game's developer (from Reddit - /u/Fragsworth)](http://www.reddit.com/r/ClickerHeroes/comments/3ajrkp/help_test_relics_version_019/csdchq8):

> Forge cores don't do anything yet. They'll be used later to upgrade
>   your items.

[Quotation from Reddit with more discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/ClickerHeroes/comments/3b31iw/forge_cores/csibzp0):

> They'll supposedly be used to upgrade relics in the near future, but
>   for now they do absolutely nothing.
>
> You get them by salvaging relics in your junk pile (i.e. "deleting"
>   them). I think the rarer the relic, the more forge cores you get.